# Making List Items Clickable/Execute JS Functions For a Pop-Up Box

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

First off, I apologize if this is an incorrect format for a question (I'll be posting a JSFiddle link).

Here is the HTML:

```
         <nav>
          <ul>
            <li><a href="#">Climate Models</a>
                <ul>
                  <li><a href="#">GFDL</a></li>
                  <li><a href="#">CGCM3</a></li>
                  <li><a href="#">CCSM</a></li>
                </ul>
            </li>
              <li id="about"><a href="#">About Data</a></li>
               <li><a href="#">Contact US</a></li>
          </ul>
        </nav>
<div id="overlay"></div>
<div id="popupabout">
    <a href="#" Id="CloseBtn">X</a>
    <br>Data</br>
</div>
```

Here is the link: http://jsfiddle.net/n3fUV/3/

The HTML code contains a navigation bar with a drop-down menu. The CSS contains styling for the menu and some styling for a pop-up box that I am trying to incorporate (it also includes the CSS for a custom-styled button). The JS contains what I thought would be correct functions to allow me to click on the "About Us" list item & have it handle the opening & closing of the pop-up box.

My question is: Is it possible to make list items clickable? If there is, I have no idea how to utilize it; I'm afraid that I'll have to re-do all of my styling for the navigation bar if I have to make them  elements in order to get this to work.

I'm sorry if I did a terrible job explaining this, as I'm fairly new to web design in general. If you don't understand something I'll try to re-explain it as best as I can. I'd appreciate any & all help.

Answer (score 1):

Code was correct but you have to select 'No wrap - in '. You can find it under "Frameworks&Extensions", it's the dropdown box where 'onLoad' is selected.

***EDIT***
You have already selected 'onLoad' so this line under HTML is not needed:

```
<body onload="initialize()">
```

And do not set the window.onload function.

```
JSFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/n3fUV/6/
```

Comment: Could I get your assistance again? For whatever reason, the code works in jsfiddle, but when I open my own HTML file and include the JS (along with linking the sorrect script type) it will not replicate what is going on in the fiddle. Does this make sense or would you like me to include the code?

Comment: Sure. If you choose in JSFiddle 'onLoad' it wrapps the JS-Code such that it will run in the 'onload' function. In your HTML file you can go with the previous defined function window.onload = function(){//YOURCODE}; Here YOURCODE will be execuded if the webpage is loaded.
Example code in JSFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/n3fUV/37/
I hope it helps. If not, please let me know.